# Convert JavaScript escape code to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I include a zero-width joiner in a VB.NET string literal? My JavaScript string is `'ല്\u200D'`.

Can I just use `'ല്' + &H200D`?

Here is the JavaScript code which I am converting to VB.NET:

```javascript
var rules = {
    a: 'അ',
    a2: 'ആ',
    k3: 'ക്\u200D'
};
```

And here’s my attempt so far:

```vb
Dim Maladic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Maladic.Add("a", "അ")
Maladic.Add("a2", "ആ")
Maladic.Add("k3", "ക്\u200D")
```

Comment: Have you considered `"ല്\u200D"`?

Comment: Its showing \u200D as string.

Comment: What is “it” and what does your entire code look like?

Comment: Ah, okay. An important thing to note here is that VB.NET is not C#.

Comment: Any thing is ok for me vb.net or c#

Comment: `"ല്\u200D"` works in C#.

Comment: if i convert "ല്\u200D" to vb.net it just show "ല്" through http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter included the zero-width joiner in the string, and it might work if you copy and paste the entire thing.

That said, you can write it in VB.NET using [`Char.ConvertFromUtf32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32(v=vs.110).aspx) as

```
Dim s = "ല്" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(&H200D)
```